# How to figure out Arguments for __soapCall()

Tags: php, xml, soap, soap-client

Im trying to access a specific method from a webservice. i can access the webservice, i know because __getFunctions() is working. What i need to know is which arguments i have to pass, to call getItem(). In SoapUI a request looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:int="http://webservice.mks.com/2009/Integrity" xmlns:sch="http://webservice.mks.com/2009/Integrity/schema">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <int:getItem>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0 transactionId="?" sch:ItemId="8720303">
            <sch:Username>--</sch:Username>
            <sch:Password>--</sch:Password>
            <sch:InputField>State</sch:InputField>
         </arg0>
      </int:getItem>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I think i have to pass a ItemId, Username, Password and InputField. But i have no Idea in which way i have to. I am using php and i called the method like this:

```
$result = $client->__soapCall('getItem',array('arg0'=>array('transactionId'=>'?','ItemId'=>'8720303','InputField'=>'State', 'Username'=>'--','Password'=>'--')));
```